# How can I compare two datetime values in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I need to compare two `datetime` values in SQL Server 2005 as below.

```
 case when min(@datetime1) < max(@datetime2) then 0 else 1 end
```

I tried with the above condition even converting the `datetime` datatype into `varchar`. But I am not able to execute it. Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you getting an error or just not the results you want?

Comment: Why are you using `min` and `max` on the values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have extra and unnecessary parenthesis around your `DateTime` variables when comparing - try this:

```
declare @datetime1 datetime 
set @datetime1 = '2008-09-03 10:42:46.000' 

declare @datetime2 datetime 
set @datetime2 = '2009-01-20 19:26:16.053' 

select 
    case when @datetime1 < @datetime2 then 0 else 1 end
```

Works just fine for me, and return the value `0` when executed.

Also, you don't need any `MIN()` or `MAX()` functions or anything like that at all - just compare the two variables and that's all there really is!

Comment: hi..My exact requirement : SELECT a=CASE WHEN min(CREATED_ON) < max(CREATED_ON) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END FROM Table1 WHERE Id1 = 224 AND id2 = 11824 GROUP BY CREATED_ON.Here CREATED_ON is the datetime column fetched from database.I get the result if i give the created_on value dynamically like '2008-09-03 10:42:46.000' rather than fetching the datetime value from the database.i even checked with converting the datetime column into varchar.But i didnot get the result .Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

i tried same query then 
i got answer and this query is

```
" SELECT a=CASE WHEN min(OrderDate) < max(OrderDate) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END FROM Orders WHERE OrderID = 10248 AND EmployeeID = 5 GROUP BY OrderDate "
```

and this is working correctly..

Comment: What are the `MIN()` and `MAX()` functions for?? Doesn't really make a lot of sense here, since you only have a single value......

Comment: hi..My exact requirement : SELECT a=CASE WHEN min(CREATED_ON) < max(CREATED_ON) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END FROM Table1 WHERE Id1 = 224 AND id2 = 11824 GROUP BY CREATED_ON.Here CREATED_ON is the datetime column fetched from database.I get the result if i give the created_on value dynamically like '2008-09-03 10:42:46.000' rather than fetching the datetime value from the database.i even checked with converting the datetime column into varchar.But i didnot get the result .Any solution?

Comment: @Mira: hi mira this query "SELECT a=CASE WHEN min(CREATED_ON) < max(CREATED_ON) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END FROM Table1 WHERE Id1 = 224 AND id2 = 11824 GROUP BY CREATED_ON" is directly work in SQL. i tried same query then i got answer and this query is " SELECT a=CASE WHEN min(OrderDate) < max(OrderDate) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
FROM Orders WHERE OrderID = 10248 AND EmployeeID = 5
GROUP BY OrderDate "..

Answer (score 0):

You probably have some null values in CREATED_ON column.